# How to know the call graphs of the functions in libc?

Tags: c, linux, libc, call-graph, nm

I'd like to know the call graph of functions in libc. For examples, what functions does `puts()` call. Is there an easy way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: [strace(1) - trace system calls and signals](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace)

Comment: For runtime analysis when debug symbols are available, you could use [perf record](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-record.1.html) with the ``--call-graph=dwarf`` option, then view the results with ``perf report --call-graph graph``. That only gives you the graph for the functions that were actually called in a given execution of a program though.

Comment: Is this question about glibc?